# 429 Too Many Requests, Fetch to much on my API with React

Tags: reactjs, api, http-status-code-429

I'm trying to fetch like 5 API which caused this error and now my page wont show anything.
I've been told to use setTimout to fix it. But i never use setTimout and having hard time using it.
Can someone show me the right way to setTimeout so it wont caused error.

The code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const loadData = async() =>{
      const anime = await fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime`);
      const value = await anime.json()
      setData(value.data)
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
      loadData();
  },[])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout function using this code

`setTimeout(() => {loadData();}, 3000);`

Where 3000 is to execute in 3 seconds (time in miliseconds)

Hope that help u.

Regards.

Comment: Should every API that i request have different milisecond?

Comment: If each request are inside loadData() with await is not neccesary because await wait to finish the fetch request and when this fetch finish, continue with next step.

If you call different functions inside useEffects this functions will be called "X" times, but if u have 1 function and this have 5 requests with await the request should exec secuently. (Sorry if my english is not perfect haha).

Comment: Ok no problem, i get it. Thanks